Why doesn't centrifugal force change instantly?
If I'm riding my dirt bike on  a rocky road, centrifugal force keeps the front wheel rolling in a straight line so I can take my hands off the handlebars without worry.   But if I hit a rock and the front wheel is suddenly forced off by 10 degrees, it returns back to the original direction.  Why doesn't it want to instantly force the bike in the new direction? Why doesn't the centrifugal force change instantly?

This behavior is not caused by centrifugal force, but rather by conservation of angular momentum.
If you take any spinning object, and draw an arrow aligned with the axis of rotation, that arrow represents the angular momentum vector. The direction of this arrow will not change unless an external torque is applied. The faster the spin and the more massive the spinning object is, the more difficult it will be to change the direction of the arrow.
Furthermore, as you'll see when riding a bike, a torque attempting to rotate a spinning object in a new direction will cause it to rotate in a direction at 90° to the applied torque. This is why when gravity tries to tip your spinning bike wheel sideways (say downward to the right), the front of the wheel is pulled back and to the right, keeping the bike above its center of gravity. The bike is designed the way it is to take advantage of this gyroscopic behavior and create stability.
Actually while a contributing factor, this gyro effect is not the primary reason the bike automatically corrects its motion. An in depth analysis is presented here

Looking from above, when any spinning wheel is nudged anticlockwise it always responds by trying to rotate the spin axis so that the axis is vertical and the wheel is rotating anticlockwise around the axis. This rotation of the axis tends to pull the bike back to the upright direction.  It always tries to the match the rotation direction to the the nudge direction. there is a limit to how much you can keep nudging in one direction due to this reaction, because the nudge instead of altering the axis is just trying to alter the speed of rotation.
Intuitively you can think of this torque reaction at the result of a delayed reaction when the momentum is altered at one point on the wheel that momentum is redirected a quarter turn later in the rotation of the wheel. Because the reaction cannot happen until the wheel has completed a quarter turn, there is a small delay.
